# Execute a request with robospice every 2 minutes

Tags: android, robospice

I want to call a webservice using robospice, and if the call fail, retry it after 2 minutes until succeed.

So I'm wondering how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IntentService` described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). You can run a loop within it that would send request to server and wait 2min over again.